# Reading an Excel file with united cells in Python

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an [excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHI2z.png) of the following type (the problem described below is driven by the presence of the united cells).

I am using *read_excel* from *pandas* to read it.

**What I want:** I would like to use the values in the first column as an index, and to have the values in the third column combined in one cell, e.g. like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R4wM.png).

**What I get** from directly applying *read_excel* can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsWkl.png).

If needed: please see the code used to read the file below (I am reading it from google drive in google colab):

```
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ExampleFile.xlsx'
pd.read_excel(path, header = 0, index_col = 0)
```

Could you please help?
Please let me know if anything in the question is unclear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to accomplish it. I created the xls similar to yours, the first column had a heading of sno

```
# fill the null values with values from previous rows
df=df.ffill()

# combine the rows where class is the same and create a new column
df=df.assign(comb=df.groupby(['class'])['type'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x)))

# drop the duplicated rows
df2=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['class','comb'])[['class','comb']]
```

```
    class   comb
0   fruit   apple,orange
2   toys    car,truck,train
```